# Using the same chain folder for both Parity and Mist/Ethereum Wallet

Tags: blockchain, mist, parity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have been having some issues with the Ethereum Wallet and after days of on/off syncing I decided to use parity, which works like a charm so far. However, I would like to use the Mist browser to play with solidity and I don't want to have to download the chain for both mist and parity.

Is there anyway I could specify to the Ethereum Wallet where the chain is and point it at parity's chain?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options here.

- You could **use the Parity browser to play with Solidity**. After running `parity ui` or opening a browser on http://127.0.0.1:8180/ you can navigate to the *Contracts* view, click *Develop*, and start coding, compiling and deploying solidity smart contracts.

[image: Screenshot]

- If you insist on using Mist, you could <del>simply</del> attach it to Parity. To do this you have to run Parity with the extra flag `--geth` first and run Mist afterwards. Mist will detect Parity and use it as chain provider. However, it is a very unstable setup and I would not recommend it.

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*

Comment: Heh, I could smell it, but your information is answering the question directly, so thank you! Why is using parity --geth with mist unstable? Isn't just pointing a different folders?